# How to remove all Docker containers

Tags: linux, docker

I want to remove all of my docker containers at once. I tried to use $ docker rm [container_id] to do so, but it removed only  one container, not all.

Is there any way to remove all docker containers using one single line of code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove containers based on status:

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps --filter status=exited -q)
```

Note:

- The "-v" option that will delete any volumes associated with the containers.

To clean out all containers on my development machine:

```
docker rm -v -f $(docker ps -qa)
```

Note:

- The "-f" option will force the removal of a running container

Comment: I would suggest adding `--filter status=dead` too. It doesn't come up often, but can. Also, would suggest including `docker rmi $(docker images --dangling=true -q)` to clean up any images that aren't in use any more.

Comment: Stop All container
 | $ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)   and Remove All containers | $ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

Answer (score 7):

As from `Docker 1.13.0` --- `Docker API 1.25`:

```
docker container prune
```

Output:

```
WARNING! This will remove all stopped containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Containers:
df226cc24539833a1c88f46bfa382ebe2e89c21805288f5e6bfc37cb7f662505
993bd58faaa22cb5dbc263eca33c8d1a241bd0a1f73b082e23e3a249fe1dfc0d
...

Total reclaimed space: 13.88MB
```

See more on [docker container prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/)

There is [docker versioning matrix](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.34/#section/Versioning) for better understanding docker versions (current is `Docker 17.12` --- `Docker API 1.35`)

Answer (score 4):

For Windows:

```
C:\> for /F %i in ('docker ps -qa') do docker rm %i
```

Answer (score 3):

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Comment: Wouldn't do this. It'll delete any storage containers you've created.

Comment: The question asked how to "remove all docker containers". Ie. including storage containers

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows (PowerShell):**

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 2):

**on Ubuntu**

```
sudo docker ps -qa | xargs -n1 sudo docker rm
```

Answer (score 2):

These two commands if you want to remove all container or image

for container

```
sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

for images

```
sudo docker image remove -f $(sudo docker images -a -q)
```

by using -f flag we can remove the container forcefully

Answer (score 1):

I can show you an amazing trick which helps you to be a better Linux user.
by typing `docker ps -a | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs docker rm` all containers will be removed. first, you list all docker containers, then separate all container ids then, remove all of them in one line of command.

Answer (score 0):

i do it with a bash script loop and a docker rm command:

```
$ for id in $(docker ps -aq); do docker rm $id; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Killing Active Containers:
`for /F %i in ('docker ps') do docker kill %i`

Remove Passive Containers:
`for /F %i in ('docker ps -qa') do docker rm %i`

It is works in Docker 17.xx

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following line

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q) || true && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) || true && docker rmi -f $(docker images -q) || true
```

If you are using jenkins or Gitlb CI/CD, just running `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` or any other relevant command would fail if there are no containers or images. With the above line, it will be prevented.